# Use function as a variable when using mat tree

Tags: angular

I'm trying to do a tree menu but I have a function in my component that will either show the element or hide it. since i'm generating it with the tree I cannot give every element different function, so I have the data model as it's shown in the tutorial for mat tree where I have the function as a string therefor node.function but this doesn't work. How do I make it work? Also i cannot access the function because it's in a different component from where i'm exporting the data.

```
<mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild">
            <li [@sideNavAnimations]="node.function ? 'SHOW' : 'HIDE'" matTreeNodeToggle>
              <a mat-list-item>
                <mat-icon>{{node.icon}}</mat-icon>
                <span [@sideNavAnimations]="sideNavStatus == 'OPEN' ? 'SHOW' : 'HIDE'">{{node.name | translate}}</span>
              <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
                {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
              </mat-icon>
              </a>
            <ul [class.tree-invisible]="!treeControl.isExpanded(node)">
              <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </mat-nested-tree-node>
```

Also I'm not sure how to correctly name this question so if you have suggestion iI'll be happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with a very easy solution.
You can pass function multiple was.

This way you can pass the function and if the function expects some arguments you can pass those too:

```
function : () => this.myFunction()
```

This should pass the function so you can execute it later:

```
function : this.myfunction
```

And this should pass the return value of the function:

```
 function : this.myfunction()
```

and then in html I just used `node.function/node.function(argument)`.